# Why I'm getting a proxy error when running npm install?

Tags: npm

I created a npm project on my work machine. This machine has NPM configured with a custom proxy and register.

I cloned this project on a different machine, and when I ran `npm i`, I got the following error:

```
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to <<registry-name>> failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <<registry-name>>
```

Which is weird, I wouldn't think that my NPM configurations would be tied to the project itself.

Anyhow, I tried removing any proxy/registry related configurations from the second machine:

```
> npm config delete registry
> npm config delete proxy
> npm config delete https-proxy
```

Now they are set back to their default values. However, I'm still getting the very same error. How can I fix this?

Comment: seems your custom registry is not in a public network

Comment: Yeah, that's right, it's in a private network that's only accessible through a VPN. But the thing is, why is NPM trying to go through the registry in the first place? The registry was already set back to the default one

Comment: Maybe you set another proxy value in the global npm config